# Move View up/down with Keyboard ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am working on a chat application similar to whatsapp etc. It has a tableview in view controller and a text field and button in the bottom toolbar. I came across the various question on sliding the view upwards and using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412395/ios-why-has-moved-toolbar-gap-to-keyboard) I managed to slide the view upwards. However I want to dismiss the keyboard and the view comes down and fits the screen .I tried using tap gesture and click on return button but nothing seems to work. How do I do make the view slide down and keyboard disappear?

Moreover how can i change the width of text field so that multiple lines can appear when the user is writing the message?

Comment: try to use textfielddidbeginediting and textfielddidendediting delegate methods

Answer (score 1):

you can add tap gesture event to tableview cell and also you can use touch event method when user click on tableview then according to keyboard previous state you can display or hide keyboard. Hope this will help to u.

Answer (score 0):

Use textFieldShouldReturn to resign first responder status (dismiss the keyboard) and slide the view up.

Personally I do it this way:

1. I register for notifications to know when the keyboard will be shown, and when it will be hidden.
2. When the keyboard appears, I set the view insets to include the size of the keyboard.
3. Slide the view up
4. When the keyboard will disappear, I set the insets to zero.

**TextField Delegate Method to hide the keyboard when the Return button is tapped**

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField;
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO; // We do not want the UITextField to insert line-breaks.
}
```

**Register for keyboard appear/disappear notifications**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    // Register for notifications for when the keyboard will appear and disappear 
    [self registerForKeyboardNotifications];
}

// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                              selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                  name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
// Original code for this part here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16044603/4518324
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)note 
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = note.userInfo;
    NSTimeInterval duration = [userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    UIViewAnimationCurve curve = [userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];

    CGRect keyboardFrameEnd = [userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    keyboardFrameEnd = [self.view convertRect:keyboardFrameEnd fromView:nil];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | curve animations:^{
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, keyboardFrameEnd.size.width, keyboardFrameEnd.origin.y);
    } completion:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification *)note 
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = note.userInfo;
    NSTimeInterval duration = [userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    UIViewAnimationCurve curve = [userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];

    CGRect keyboardFrameEnd = [userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    keyboardFrameEnd = [self.view convertRect:keyboardFrameEnd fromView:nil];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | curve animations:^{
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, keyboardFrameEnd.size.width, keyboardFrameEnd.origin.y);
    } completion:nil];
}
```

I have created sample code that involves resizing the view when they keyboard is shown or dismissed.

https://github.com/gingofthesouth/KeyboardHideShow

Comment: I am not using scrollview anywhere. :\

Comment: I have updated the example code for a standard UIView and created an example project to demonstrate it (github link included).

Comment: As for your second question, you need to use a UITextView if you want multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

I got it right . I had another method called out when keyboard is dismissed which fit the view frame as per requirement which is View.frame-keyboard.frame.height. Thanks anyways!:)